# Running a python script on a remote machine through ssh

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, cygwin, paramiko

The remote machine has Cygwin installed and I have done

```
$echo "PATH=\$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Python27" >> .bash_profile
then, source .bash_profile (after doing this I am able to run a Python script from cygwin terminal).
```

Now, from Pyscripter installed in my laptop, I am trying to run hello_world in the remote machine through paramiko:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('135.24.237.167',username = 'cyg_server',password = 'force')

stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("/cygdrive/c/Python27/python /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/hello_world.py")

##But I get the following error:

stderr.readlines()

[u"C:\\Python27\\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/hello_world.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory\r\n"]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Paramiko is too raw, as I believe. Try using fabric.

Sample code would be:

```
from fabric.api import *

env.key_filename = /path/to/your/pem/file

def mem_usage():
   run('free -m')

execute(mem_usage, host="user@IP_or_hostname")
```

Or if you do not have a pem file, you can leave that line and just enter the password when prompted.